# Django form validation not working for all the fields

Tags: django, forms, validation

new in the field and struggling with a form validation in practice. I have created a form which i use as data input for a search in the DB. Form validation is only being triggered for the first field while the others seems not to be taken in consideration, bellow the code:

Form description:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):  
        cnp_nbr = forms.IntegerField(label='CNP', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control' }), required=False)  
        first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),  required=False) 
        last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),  required=False)

        class Meta():
            model = Clients                                
            fields = ('cnp_nbr','first_name','last_name')

        def clean(self):  # most used!!!
            all_clean_data = super().clean()
            cnp_nbr = all_clean_data['cnp_nbr']
            first_name = all_clean_data['first_name']
            last_name = all_clean_data['last_name']

            if  cnp_nbr is None or (first_name is None and last_name is None):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Enter f1 or f2&f3")

            super().clean()
```

Views:

```
class ClientsSearch(generic.FormView):
        form_class = forms.SearchForm
        template_name = "administration/clients_search.html"
        success_url = reverse_lazy('administration:searchresults')

        def form_valid(self, form):     
            self.request.session['cnp_nbr'] = form.cleaned_data['cnp_nbr']
            self.request.session['first_name'] = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            self.request.session['last_name'] = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            return super().form_valid(form)


class SearchResults (generic.ListView):
        model = models.Clients
        template_name='administration/search_results.html'
        context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

        def get_queryset(self): 
                return self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(cnp_nbr__exact=self.request.session['cnp_nbr']) | Q(first_name__exact=self.request.session['first_name']) & Q(last_name__exact=self.request.session['last_name']) 
            )
```

HTML for search form:

```
<form method="POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search_submit" name = "search_submit" type="submit" > Search</button>
</form>
```

Validation is working only for cnp_nbr, i even tested them one by one.
This works   :

```
if  cnp_nbr is None:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Enter field")
```

This doesnt

```
if  first_name is None:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Enter field")
```

Search is working just fine! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's because a not required `IntegerField` will be `None` if it's empty, whereas a not required `CharField` will be `''` (the empty string) if it's empty. So you should not check `last_name is None` but just `not last_name`:

```
if cnp_nbr is None or not (first_name or last_name):
```

Note: Also I'd advise you to never directly assume the keys are present in the form's cleaned_data: Do `first_name = all_clean_data.get('first_name')` instead.

Note2: Why don't you just make `cnp_nbr` required since your `ValidationError` will trigger in any case if `cnp_nbr` isn't filled?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input!  cnp_nbr is not required if the user enters the first &last name. What i found yet strange is that the ValidationError is now working corectly but having following logic:   if  cnp_nbr is None and (first_name =='' or last_name =='') , i would have expected to use if  cnp_nbr is None OR (first_name =='' and last_name =='')

Comment: That’s not what your if statement checks. You use `or` so if either isn’t filled you raise an error, meaning you require both. Also you don’t require first & last name but first **or** last name.

Comment: Learn your Boolean operators: not A and not B = not (A or B); not A or not B = not (A and B)